# Why facebook redirect url is not recognized by get_access token end point

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I am setting up a new login to get post from a facebook business page as well as messenger plate form access. Therefore, I am setting a facebook login within my application. then facebook send me back error message

I have succeeded  to get a login code into my redirect url. however, within the callback function, I try to get facebook access token, and got stacked
I have checked my facebook redirect url settings as well as my code, I am pretty sure both redirect url on facebook settings and my app is same, Thank you for help from your people

```
[HttpGet, Route("facebookCallBack"), AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> facebookCallBack([FromUri]string code)
        {
            string facebookAppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"];
            string facebookAppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"];
            string fbBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookApiRootUrl"];
            var redirectUrl = "{my url}";
            var url = fbBaseUrl + "oauth/access_token?" 
                    + "client_id=" + facebookAppId 
                    + "&client_secret=" + facebookAppSecret 
                    + "&code=" + code 
                    + "&redirect_uri="+ redirectUrl;

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var request = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var strContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Json(new { data = strContent , url= Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri , urlx = redirectUrl });
        }
```

I expect the output of the actual access token but facebook give me  "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog".

Comment: So, you're positive the redirect_uri is *exactly* the same as the one you passed with the redirect to the auth server?

Comment: Yes, although when the url redirect back, it adds a parameter code but it doesnt metter right? I mean https://app.domain.com/facebookcallback is same with https://app.domain.com/facebookcallback?code=abcdefg, right?

Comment: If they're performing exact matches against the registered url, then it would need to be the same. Are you sending it back with the code query param to the token request?

Comment: I tried 2 types of redirect url https://myapp.mydomain.com/facebookcallback?code=mycode and https://myapp.mydomain.com/ as redirect Url, facebook seems not accept the 1st one since it tells me the url is not listed in the callback url, however it also not accept the second type without the parameter as the exception showed above.

Comment: Check the actual value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in the browser address bar when the Facebook login dialog is shown. That _exact_ value is what you need to supply again in the API call.

Comment: I've checked the url, the redirect url is same as the url in the facebook dialog

Comment: Hi dear 04FS and @ChiefTwoPencils, I have solved my problem, thank you for both of your help, I used myapp.mydomain.com/facebookCallBack instead of myapp.mydomain.com/facebookcallback since I believe the capitalized letters does not make a big deal. sorry, this is a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry friends, I made a stupid mistake, I used myapp.mydomain.com/facebookCallBack instead of myapp.mydomain.com/facebookcallback I thought the browser and api will transfer the capitalized letters into lowercase letters automatically, and even though I thought facebook will not check for upper/lower case on redirect url. I was wrong, facebook api will check the exact match of the redirect url and the redirect it is case sensitive.

Comment: And a complain, why facebook change its api so frequently. This drives me crazy, I am a new facebook developer for a small company, and I feel so mad about this.